# Selection by coordinates, python-xarray

Tags: multidimensional-array, python-xarray

I have a small python-xarray `DataArray` I call `TINY` with dimensions `x`,`y`, and `t`. `TINY` represents a processed subset of a larger `DataSet` I call `HUGE` with dimensions `x'`,`y'` and `t'` and variables `foo`, `bar` and `baz`

I'm looking for a way to **select** a Dataset from `HUGE` using `TINY` coordinates.(all coordinates and coordinate pairs in tiny exist in huge)

I hastily [drafted](https://www.draw.io/) up the following illustration

[image]

The selection returns a subset of `HUGE` that shares the `coords` of `TINY`. What is returned is a `DataSet`. Is there some shorthand x-array method to handle this?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear - do `TINY` & `HUGE` share dimensions? How do the values in `TINY` reference where to select the data from in `HUGE`?

Comment: Yes. TINY & HUGE share dimensions.
Its coordinates are a subset of HUGE coordinates

Comment: What is in `TINY` that identifies what you want to select in `HUGE`? Coordinates? Where they share data? A code example would cut through it if it's difficult to describe

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I've updated the illustration to help clarify,

TINY shares coordinates with HUGE. All coordinates in TINY can be found in huge. Id like to select a subset of HUGE based on TINY coordinates.  (not TINY values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.reindex_like()`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.reindex_like.html) will give you `HUGE`'s data over `TINY`'s coordinates - is that what you're looking for?

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for. 

When I write `HUGE.reindex_like(TINY)` It seams to return a Dataset with the dimensions of `HUGE`. When I write `TINY.reindex_like(HUGE)` It returns a Dataset with the dimensions of `TINY`. 

The problem I'm running into is that while I may be reducing the size of HUGE in my selection, I do not get get all the variables of HUGE. I may not be doing this correctly.

Comment: We might need an example... I had thought that the two shared dimenisons

Comment: So the context for this problem is image-processing or.computer vision on a time series of very large images.  `Huge` represents pixels at `x`,`y`,`t` with variables `r`,`g`,`b`.  
  
My algorithm does a lot of filtering and manipulation of pixel values to yield something called `TINY`. It has `x`,`y`, and `t` like huge, but focuses on a much smaller area. and no longer has variables `r`,`g`,`b` but some derived variable like `probability`.  `TINY` is a filtered version of `Huge`. As such it focuses on an area a lot smaller than `HUGE` but is still on the same coordinate system.

Comment: My problem is trying trying to examine or debug tiny by displaying an `r`,`g`,`b` composite of `HUGE` at, or surrounding the location of `TINY` points.  
For my problem TINY typically ends up being a 20 by 20 (`x`,`y`)  pixel bounding box, that exists on about only  2 or 3 slices on my time axis(`t`)

Comment: Why doesn't `HUGE.reindex_like(TINY)` give you what you need? Can you post a smaller example?

Comment: Oh. Wow. That does work.
I was thrown off by the fact that when `TINY`only occupies a single value along the time axis it ends up returning ALL `t` from `HUGE`  during the re-index.  
It does the reindex correctly on `x` and `y` coords, which is already a lot better than what I had previously.